# How to store & retrieve data from ajax response in an global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

the below code is an example of *retrieving username and email address from ajax response*.
My Question is:
1.how to store **user.name inside uname** and **user.email in uemail**. where both are global variable.

---

*code:*

```
var uname;
var uemail;

function getUserInfo() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
    data: null,
    success: function (resp) {
        user = resp;
        console.log(user);

        localStorage.setItem("Name", user.name);
        localStorage.setItem("Email", user.email);



        $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
        $('#uEmail').text('Your Email ' + user.email);
        $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
        //$('jName').text(user.name);
        //$('jEmail').text(user.jEmail);
        alert(jName);
        alert(jEmail);

    },
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

### }

Comment: Use `Promise/callback`

Comment: It's pretty simple:

`uname = user.name;
uemail = user.email;
`

Comment: @AhmedKhan is right. You can directly assign value to global variables  ie           uname = user.name;  and uemail = user.email;

Answer (score 0):

When using global variable you are able to assign values directly like this

```
uname = user.name; uemail = user.email;
```

Comment: how to display uName in another webform using its div Id.